# Spring Conditional bean on @EnableWebMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How can I control a bean's creation depending on whether there's not another, different bean in the project annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`?

I tried

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)
```

as suggested [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-mvc-auto-configuration.html) but no luck. i get this contradicting state when @EnableWebMvc is there

> WebMvcAutoConfiguration:
>         Did not match:
>            - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) **found beans of type** 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport' org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration (OnBeanCondition)

and also

> ProblemModulesRegisterer matched:
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) **did not find any beans** (OnBeanCondition)

So it found and not found beans of type `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`

As another attempt, I also compared the registered beans with and without `@EnableWebMvc` and noticed that without it, there's a bean called `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration`. So I tried a `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class)` but it still doesn't work. It shows this contradicting state

> WebMvcAutoConfiguration **matched**:
>         - @ConditionalOnClass found required classes 'javax.servlet.Servlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet', 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)
>         - found 'session' scope (OnWebApplicationCondition)
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

and also

> ProblemModulesRegisterer matched:
>         - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) **did not find any beans** (OnBeanCondition)

So `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` matched (was created) and a dependency of missing `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` also matched

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that you can only use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` in an autoconfigure context. The javadoc says

> The condition can only match the bean definitions that have been processed by the application context so far and, as such, it is strongly recommended to use this condition on **auto-configuration classes only**

I was trying to use the annotation in a regular application. For more info on creating an autoconfiguration module check the [official doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html). Once I did it like that (specifically, adding the class to `spring.factories`), it worked to detect `@EnableWebMvc` by using

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

`@ConditionalOnMissingBean` will execute your code and what you want is opposite - **not** execute. Perhaps you should try a mixture of `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@AutoConfigureAfter` provided in the example in the link you've posted.

I've used in few database related beans and manipulation of `Conditional`s and `AutoconfigureAfter` actually does the trick. Just need a better understanding of your application to be able to provide more concrete suggestion

Comment: @conditional on what class? what i need is ANY class, as long as it's annotated with `@EnableWebMvc`. Same question for configureAfter. after what? the goal is to have a generic Spring solution, not something limited to my current implementation of `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: on `Configuration`. Single-point extract the logic which you require and handle it conditionally. Only allow execution in case aspects are present

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotated bean creation will happen **after** `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` creation.

From spring [**docs**](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html),

> Beans on which the current bean depends. Any beans specified are
>   guaranteed to be created by the container before this bean.

Use `@DependsOn` annotation **in addition to** `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` as explained [**here**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on).

and also make sure you are doing these inside a `@configuration` annotated class.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"webMvcConfigurationSupport"})
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)
     public FileProcessor fileProcessor(){
        return new FileProcessor();
    }
```

In this example, fileProcessor will be created only when webMvcConfigurationSupport bean is missing.

Comment: this doesn't work. it gives `A component required a bean named 'webMvcConfigurationSupport' that could not be found.` on startup. And I don't know the name of the actual bean. That's why i'm trying to do it based on the annotation @EnableWebMvc`

Comment: why you want to avoid this bean?